# Var_dump("0") returns string(5) "0"

Tags: php

I have a csv file that I want to insert into a table. Anywhere that the value is 0, I want it to be an empty string. When I check if ($data !== "0") it doesn't work, because apparently my `$data` is not a 0, but a `string(5)` "0" when var_dump'ed.

I've tried: `html_entity_decode, htmlentities, htmlspecialchars, htmlspecialchars_decode`.  I've also tried to compare with `&#-48;` (without the -) which is the html code for 0 I guess.

This is what I currently have. The csv has everything in "" so I remove those with `preg_replace("([\"])", "", $data);`

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <?php foreach($header as $key => $h): ?>
            <th><?= preg_replace("([\"])", "", $h); ?></th>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($data_rows as $key => $data_row): ?>
        <tr class="tbody-tr">
            <?php foreach($data_row as $key => $data): ?>
            <td><?php
                $data = preg_replace("([\"])", "", $data);
                var_dump($data); 
                if ($data !== "0") { 
                    echo $data;
                } else {
                    echo "";
                }
            ?></td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Did you try `trim`?

Comment: yes, that didn't work either :(

Comment: oh, never mind. It worked! Thanks

Comment: If `var_dump()` indicates invisible characters, you can check in a hex editor what characters/bytes those are.

Comment: `urlencode($data);` is a quick & simple way to get non-displayable byte values shown as %-encoded for debugging purposes.

Comment: _“The csv has everything in "" so I remove those with preg_replace("([\"])", "", $data);”_ - sounds like you are reading this data from the file in a less than ideal way to begin with. That part should be using https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: What returns chr($data); ? P.S It's not a good idea to create CSV in your html file?

Comment: With quotationmarks like those you rather get syntax or symbol errors.